# Replacing string+number in a file using Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a file in which I would like to find and replace the figure in an expression as follows

```
...
.param vthna=0.466
.param vthnb=0.466
...
```

For example, I would like to change the original `".param vthna=0.466"` to `".param vthna=0.467"` where 0.467 is a randomly generated number, while keep other lines unchanged (i.e., the line of .param vthnb=0.466 is still kept the same).

My code for doing this is

```
for line in f_in:
line=re.sub(r".param vthna=[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+",".param vthna="+vthna_s,line)
f_out.write(line)
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

but finally all the number/float/digits in my file were replaced by the target expression. That is, the line of `.param vthna=0.466` becomes `.param vthna=0.467, but`.param vthnb=0.466`becomes`.param vthnb=.param vthna=666..param vthna=666
`. Could anyone provide me with any clue to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not try to match `.param vth=0.466` then?

Comment: Hi Jerry, the value of 'vth' in my code is actually a randomly generated number, which means, every time a random number is generated, it will replace the old one. Sorry for not describing clearly in my question, and hope I explained well this time.

Comment: What do you mean with "all the numbers in my file were replaced" exactly?

Comment: Hi @T.C. I have other numbers in the file that I want to keep unchanged. My aim is just change the specific ".param vth=xxx" where "xxx" is an old number to a new generated number. Thanks.

Comment: I give an answer i hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hi T.C., thanks a lot for your help. I tried your code and now I found where the problem hided. See the regex `.param vth=[-+]=?\d*\.\d+` where the second equal symbol should be removed. This time the regex can be successfully matched and the script works well for me. Thanks again T.C. and sorry for wasting your time with the stupid question. :)

Comment: @Yueguoguo Oh the second equal wasn't deliberately, but if my answer works for you, you can accept my answer that the question is closed, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem exactly, but i tried to prey it... If thats not your problem, i apologize...

so first you open 2 filestreams, f_in and f_out:

```
 f_in = open("input.file")
 f_out = open("output.file", "w")
```

then you iterate through your input file and look up the line ".param vth=xxx" and replace it with a randomly generated number

```
 randomlyGenNumber = 0.214 # thats the random number

 for line in f_in:
     line = re.sub(r".param vth=[-+]?\d*\.\d+", ".param vth="+str(randomlyGenNumber), line)
     f_out.write(line)
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Comment: Yes T.C. your understanding are correct. My problem is that the `re.sub()` expression did not work well. That is, it replaced all the numbers in my f_in file to `.param vth="+str(randomlyGenNumber)`, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: For example, I have another statement `.param vthnb=0.466` in my input file which should be kept unchanged. But after the execution, it became like `.param vthnb=.param vth=<randomlyGenNumber>`.

Comment: @Yueguoguo please edit your question and write the other lines !!

Comment: All numbers in my input file were replaced by `param vth="+str(randomlyGenNumber)`.

Comment: PLEASE edit your question with more information about your input file, that i can create a new regular expression......

Comment: See my answer to you in the original comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
\.param vthna=.*
```

You should use this.This will replace your string without disturbing

`.param vthnb`